# What is this exquisite looking shrub?

Tags: identification, leaves, flowers

Found on Bainbridge island in pacific northwest. It’s about 5-7 ft / 1.5-2.1 meters tall and equally wide.

[image]

Comment: Some kind of lacecap hydrangea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *Hydrangea macrophylla*, one of the lace cap varieties rather than a 'mophead' type. They are deciduous and prefer partial or dappled shade in soil that does not dry out frequently, and need plenty of space because, as you mention, they get rather large over time. They should not be hard pruned or pruned at all if possible, with only dead wood removed in spring as they start to leaf out. Intermittent/selective stem pruning can be carried out if necessary, and renovation pruning on older, unproductive shrubs, but this type of heavier pruning will mean no flowers for a year or two because they produce flowers on the previous year's wood. https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/shrubs/hydrangea/lacecap-hydrangea-care.htm